# Absolute pathing does not return variable's definition

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, visual-studio-code

When I try to import a function using an absolute path i.e.

```
const test = require("@/functions")
```

the function's parameters and definitions aren't defined, only returning `:any`.

However, if I do the same import with relative pathing i.e.

```
require("../../functions")
```

it defines it correctly.

I even have a jsconfig.json defined:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [
                "./src/*"
            ],
            "#/*": [
                "./*"
            ]
        }
    },
}
```

What I expect to see:

[image]

What I actually get:

[image]

Comment: But those are 2 different paths, `../../functions` is two directories higher up than `functions`

Comment: @GMaiolo woops typo, forgot to add the `@`

Comment: Have you tried removing the `./` from `./src/*` and doing `src/*` instead?

Comment: @GMaiolo no difference

Comment: Care to share `functions` absolute path and the file you're trying to import that file's path as well?

Comment: the importing works, it's just that vsode doesn't show me what's contained in the file. It's more of a display issue within vscode.

Comment: I hate to say it, but this might be a rare situation where screenshots might be welcome. If I'm understanding you then you mean that the "code runs" from the `require()`. but the UI of VSCode is not doing what you expect? Not completely sold on that being the right type of question for this site if that is the case, even if it's a "programming tool". <Sigh!>

Comment: @NeilLunn there are a few questions with vscode so I assume that it's kinda relevant, since it's also quite answerable and not opinion based.

Comment: I did not say it's not allowed, but just that I'm not sure I "like it". And *"there's other questions like this posted here.. "* (sic) is not really an excuse. That said, the screenshots in this context at least make it clear what your question is about.